# How to upload and add images to a project(solution explorer) folder in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Iam tried to add images to a folder in asp.net.But image not added to the folder.

aspx

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl"  OnClick="FileUploadControl_Click"  runat="server" />
<asp:Button 
        ID="Button1" 
        runat="server" 
        Text="Create" 
        class="btn"
        OnClick="Button1_Click"
   />
```

Aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(Object sender,
                       System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
                {
                    if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 1000)
                    {
                        filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                        FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Myimages") + filename);

                    }
                  }
                }
```

Here 'Myimages' is my folder.But images not added to my folder.What went wrong for me?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @KaushikMaheta:No,but not uploaded to the folder

Comment: Can you check your folder?

Comment: Why you have added `FileUploadControl_Click` event on FileUpload when you are saving from `Button1_Click` event

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal:instead of that what i need to put?

Comment: Can you check if you are upload images with more than 1000 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Myimages") + filename);
```

To

```
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Myimages/" + filename));
```

I tried your code and it worked.